# Re-assigning values to tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

Since tuple is a immutable object, following code gives an Error.

```
 tup = (1,2,3)
 tup[0] = 3
```

But the following code runs without an Error

```
a = 10
b = 20
c = 30
(a,b,c) = (b,c,a)
```

Why?

Comment: What do you mean? Of course it throws an error.

Comment: can't assign to a literal is what I'm getting.

Comment: It throws "SyntaxError: can't assign to literal"

Comment: Yep, when the code is written like this it gives an error. I will edit it coldspeed

Comment: That's not really a tuple on the left side. It just uses very similar syntax. You're not modifying a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is tuple assignment. The left hand side is just grouping of variables and would work without the parenthesis too.

It is similar to:

```
a, b, c = (b, c, a);
```

Using `()` doesn't necessarily always mean that it is a tuple. `()` can also be used for grouping an expression which is the case here.